# How to use url_for in .js function with FLASK App?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, data-science

I have deployed my Flask App in Heroku and the HTML,CSS pages were loaded from the domain created.

In my local machine, I have tried the functionalities with the URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

But In order to make it work after deployment in Heroku, I tried using use_for, which I can use it for rendering css,js files in html.

I couldn't find any possibilities to use that in .js file for calling the routing function defined in the python file.

Hereby Attached my .js code,

```
    function sendResponse(rawText) {
        var url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_response"
        $.post(url,{
            user_text:rawText
        },function(data, status){
        if(data !== "undefined"){
          console.log(data['bot_response'`enter code here`])
          var botHtml = '<p class="botText"><span>' + data['bot_response'] + '</span> </p>';
            $("#chatbox").append(botHtml);
            document.getElementById('userInput').scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 
            'smooth'});
            return data['bot_response']
            
        }
    })
  }
```

Comment: You could use `var url = window.location.origin + "/get_response";`.

Comment: In the local environment it is working, but in the Heroku URL it shows the following error, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Comment: That usually indicates a problem with Flask, not javascript, are there any errors in the Heroku logs?

Comment: Just now I figured that it is the problem with the global variables in the function, that's because it shows the internal server error...the globally referenced variable is reset to none when I called it in the other function. Is there any way to access global variables through out the functions?

Comment: You may need to add `global variablename` at the start of your function for each global variable you want to access. Otherwise python might assume they're local variables you're trying to access instead.